# Modify the size of the signup button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]
[image]

This is a form for logging in. As noted in the black screen, the registration button is small. The question is how can I make the registration button as large as in the white image
This is part of the code for the record button
Register.vue:

```
              <v-layout row>
                <v-flex xs12>
                  <v-btn class="red accent-4 margine color myfont">
                    Sign up
                  </v-btn>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Vuetify documentation, you'll find, that in order for the button to extend the full width of its container, you give it the `block` property.

Like such:

```
<v-btn class="red accent-4 margine color myfont" block>
  Sign up
</v-btn>
```

[You'll find it all in the vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/)